# How to calculate the distance between two GPS coordinates without using Google Maps API?

Tags: ruby, google-maps

I'm wondering if there's a way to calculate the distance of two GPS coordinates without relying on Google Maps API.

My app may receive the coordinates in float or I would have to do reverse GEO on the addresses.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Distance between two coordinates on earth is usually calculated using [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). This formula takes into consideration earth shape and radius. This is the code I use to calculate distance in meters.

```
def distance(loc1, loc2)
  rad_per_deg = Math::PI/180  # PI / 180
  rkm = 6371                  # Earth radius in kilometers
  rm = rkm * 1000             # Radius in meters

  dlat_rad = (loc2[0]-loc1[0]) * rad_per_deg  # Delta, converted to rad
  dlon_rad = (loc2[1]-loc1[1]) * rad_per_deg

  lat1_rad, lon1_rad = loc1.map {|i| i * rad_per_deg }
  lat2_rad, lon2_rad = loc2.map {|i| i * rad_per_deg }

  a = Math.sin(dlat_rad/2)**2 + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.sin(dlon_rad/2)**2
  c = 2 * Math::atan2(Math::sqrt(a), Math::sqrt(1-a))

  rm * c # Delta in meters
end

puts distance([46.3625, 15.114444],[46.055556, 14.508333])
# => 57794.35510874037
```

Comment: Haversine formula is also used in [Geocoder](http://rubygems.org/gems/geocoder), see file [calculations.rb](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb#L72).

Comment: This method modifies the values of `a` and `b` which is unexpected. I guess there's no need to use `.map!` instead of `.map` or to reuse `a` again.

Comment: Edited so that no longer happens.

Comment: according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System "The WGS 84 datum surface is an oblate spheroid with equatorial radius a = 6378137 m" This would suggest you should use this value for radius of earth in meters.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [geokit ruby gem](https://github.com/geokit/geokit). It does these calculations internally, but also supports resolving addresses via google and other services if you need it to.

```
require 'geokit'

current_location = Geokit::LatLng.new(37.79363,-122.396116)
destination = "37.786217,-122.41619"
current_location.distance_to(destination) 

# Returns distance in miles: 1.211200074136264
```

You can also find out the `bearing_to` (direction expressed as a float in degrees between 0-360) and `midpoint_to` (returns an object you can run .latitude and .longitude methods on).

Answer (score 6):

Just a little shorter & separated parameter version of @Lunivore's answer

```
RAD_PER_DEG = Math::PI / 180
RM = 6371000 # Earth radius in meters

def distance_between(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)
  lat1_rad, lat2_rad = lat1 * RAD_PER_DEG, lat2 * RAD_PER_DEG
  lon1_rad, lon2_rad = lon1 * RAD_PER_DEG, lon2 * RAD_PER_DEG

  a = Math.sin((lat2_rad - lat1_rad) / 2) ** 2 + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.sin((lon2_rad - lon1_rad) / 2) ** 2
  c = 2 * Math::atan2(Math::sqrt(a), Math::sqrt(1 - a))

  RM * c # Delta in meters
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure of any prepackaged solution, but it seems a fairly straightforward calculation:  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [loc gem](https://github.com/klaxit/loc) like this :

```
require 'loc'

loc1 = Loc::Location[49.1, 2]
loc2 = Loc::Location[50, 3]

loc1.distance_to(loc2)
=> 123364.76538823603 # km
```

Comment: [loc gem](https://github.com/klaxit/loc) internally also uses exactly the same [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) as described in the "accepted" answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Look at gem [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder))

If you store your coordinates in db, it calculate distance using database. But works good in other cases too.

Comment: How would I access the method in https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/calculations.rb  ?

Comment: like so ```Geocoder::Calculations.coordinates_present?```

Answer (score 1):

Converted the accepted answer to Swift 3.1 (works on Xcode 8.3), in case anyone needs it:

```
public static func calculateDistanceMeters(departure: CLLocationCoordinate2D, arrival: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Double {

    let rad_per_deg = Double.pi / 180.0 // PI / 180
    let rkm = 6371.0                    // Earth radius in kilometers
    let rm = rkm * 1000.0               // Radius in meters

    let dlat_rad = (arrival.latitude - departure.latitude) * rad_per_deg // Delta, converted to rad
    let dlon_rad = (arrival.longitude - departure.longitude) * rad_per_deg

    let lat1_rad = departure.latitude * rad_per_deg
    let lat2_rad = arrival.latitude * rad_per_deg

    let sinDlat = sin(dlat_rad/2)
    let sinDlon = sin(dlon_rad/2)
    let a = sinDlat * sinDlat + cos(lat1_rad) * cos(lat2_rad) * sinDlon * sinDlon
    let c = 2.0 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))

    return rm * c
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'rgeo'

point_1 = RGeo::Cartesian.factory.point(0, 0)
point_2 = RGeo::Cartesian.factory.point(0, 2)

p point_1.distance(point_2)
# => 2.0
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?