# Mongo Map-Reduce: group documents in a certain distance by value

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm trying to convert my aggregation query to Map-Reduce one in `MongoDB` (using Ruby driver). In my original query, I search for elements in a certain distance from a point and then group them by `NEIGHBORHOOD` value.

**Sample document**

```
{
 "_id":"5b01a2c77b61e58732920f86",
 "YEAR":2004,
 "NEIGHBOURHOOD":"Grandview-Woodland",
 "LOC":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-123.067654,49.26773386]}
}
```

**Aggregation query**

```
crime.aggregate([
{ "$geoNear": {
"near": { 
  "type": "Point", 
  "coordinates": [ -123.0837633, 49.26980201 ]
},
"query": { "YEAR": 2004 },
"distanceField": "distance",
"minDistance": 10,
"maxDistance": 10000,
"num": 100000,
"spherical": true
}},
{ "$group": {   
   "_id": "$NEIGHBOURHOOD",
   "count": { "$sum": 1 } 
}}
])
```

So the fragment of the output looks like this:

**Output**

```
{"_id"=>"Musqueam", "count"=>80}
{"_id"=>"West Point Grey", "count"=>651}
{"_id"=>"Marpole", "count"=>1367}
```

Now I'm trying to make something like this in MapReduce. In my `map function` I try to check if documents are in the correct distance (based on the answer to [THIS QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966638/how-to-calculate-the-distance-between-two-gps-coordinates-without-using-google-m)) and if so pass them along to `reduce function` in which they will be counted. But something is not right and I don't get the desired result - `count` values are too big.  What am I doing wrong?

**Map function**

```
 map = "function() {" +
  "var rad_per_deg = Math.PI/180;" +
  "var rm = 6371 * 1000;" +
  "var dlat_rad = (this.LOC.coordinates[0] - (-123.0837633)) * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var dlon_rad = (this.LOC.coordinates[1] - (49.26980201)) * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var lat1_rad = -123.0837633 * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var lon1_rad = 49.26980201 * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var lat2_rad = this.LOC.coordinates[0] * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var lon2_rad = this.LOC.coordinates[1] * rad_per_deg;" +
  "var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat_rad/2), 2) + Math.cos(lat1_rad) * Math.cos(lat2_rad) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlon_rad/2), 2);" +
  "var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));" +
  "if( rm * c < 10000) { " + 
  " emit(this.NEIGHBOURHOOD, {count: 1});" +
  "}" +
  "};"
```

**Reduce function**

```
reduce = "function(key, values) { " +
  "var sum = 0; " +
  "values.forEach(function(f) { " +
  " sum += f.count; " +
  "}); " +
  "return {count: sum};" +
  "};"
```

**Query**

```
 opts =  {
    query:{ "YEAR": 2004 },
    :out => "results", 
    :raw => true
  }
```

**Output**

```
 crime.find().map_reduce(map, reduce, opts)

 {"_id"=>"", "value"=>{"count"=>2257.0}}
 {"_id"=>"Arbutus Ridge", "value"=>{"count"=>6066.0}}
 {"_id"=>"Central Business District", "value"=>{"count"=>110947.0}}
```

Comment: What am I doing wrong? - Using map-reduce instead of aggregation. Is there any reason?

Comment: I know that Map-Reduce is not the best solution for this kind of task but I got the assignment to compare it to Aggregation.

Comment: Fair enough. First of all "NEIGHBORHOOD" !="NEIGHBOURHOOD". Secondly, you overcomplicate the emit and reduce. Lastly, mongo doesn't use Haversine formula, but rely on libgoogle libs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't know about different methods to calculate distance. I guess that means that Map-Reduce output won't be exactly the same. This spelling mistake is really embarrassing. I updated my output after correcting it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix my emit and reduce functions. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: np, we all make tpyos =) Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/ for inspiration. It has very similar usecase.