# rgeo: distance calculation between a point and a line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I am working on a hotel application (using ruby on rails), and I am trying to calculate the distance between an hotel and the sea.

I have gathered the geometry of the shoreline points in a geojson file and I am now trying to calculate the distance using the `rgeo` gem.

My findings are the following:

when using a `simple_mercator_factory`, I obtain an wrong value and when using a `spherical_factory` the distance between 2 point is correct, but I calculating the distance between a point and a line yields an error.

How can I calculate this distance ?

Comment: There're several ways, by gem or pure Ruby.

You could just check the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966638

Comment: this answer is for the distance between 2 points. I need the shortest distance between a point and a line

Comment: Oh, I see, could you give some example data of "the geometry of the shoreline points"?

Comment: And more detail may be helpful: how did you use simple_mercator_factory?What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `geographic_factory` which uses spherical calculations and can handle both point-to-point and point-to-line distance calculations.

```
factory = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
```

Parse the shoreline points from the GeoJSON file and convert them to RGeo objects using the geographic_factory:

```
shoreline_geojson = File.read('path/to/your/geojson/file')
shoreline = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(shoreline_geojson, json_parser: :json, geo_factory: factory)
```

Create an RGeo point for the hotel location using the geographic_factory:

```
hotel_location = factory.point(hotel_longitude, hotel_latitude)
```

Calculate the minimum distance between the hotel location and the shoreline points:

```
min_distance = shoreline.points.map { |point| hotel_location.distance(point) }.min
```

Now, min_distance will hold the shortest distance between the hotel and the shoreline in meters.

---

edit: you'll need to add `rgeo-geojson`

```
gem 'rgeo-geojson'
bundle install
```